# Por qué mi método no devuelve la fecha modificada?

Tags: c#, .net, class

Tengo que mostrar los datos de un compuesto químico en consola, uno de ellos es la fecha de vencimiento (que según la consigna es dos años y medio luego de la fabricación).
El método que cree devuelve la fecha inicial sin modificar.

Este es uno de mis intentos:

```
public DateTime FechaVencimiento()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse($"{AnioF}/{MesF}/{DiaF}");
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(912);
    dt = dt.Add(ts);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Logré los resultados que quería con:

```
public DateTime FechaVencimiento()
{

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse($"{AnioF}/{MesF}/{DiaF}");
    DateTime ts = dt.AddDays(912);
            
    return ts;
}
```

Aún no se porqué el anterior no funciona.

Comment: Basicamente, porque al no leer la [documentacion](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-timespan-ctor(system-int64)) pensaste que ese numero eran la cantidad de dias.. cuando en realidad son ticks... Y aca, estas haciendo lo que deberias haber hecho... o mucho mejor, podrias haber sumado 2 años y 6 meses.. si queres una respuesta mas completa, avisame y la hacemos.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan` es una estructura para medir una intervalo de tiempo. La unidad mínima usada es un `Tick` que equivale a 100 nanosegundos.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(912);
```

El código anterior crea un intervalo de tiempo de 912 ticks, es decir 0,0000912 segundos.

Esto es porque el constructor de `TimeSpan` que toma UN solo argumento lo hace por Ticks, si tú quieres introducir un intervalo de días deberías haber ocupado 4 argumentos `new TimeSpan(dias,horas,minutos,segundos)`, es decir

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(912,0,0,0);
```

O bien ocupar  la función `addDays` del Datetime.

---

Además esto

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse($"{AnioF}/{MesF}/{DiaF}");
```

Es mejor hacerlo de esta manera:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(AnioF, MesF, DiaF)
```

Y tú función puede quedar reducida a:

```
public DateTime FechaVencimiento()
     => new DateTime(AnioF, MesF, DiaF).AddDays(912);
```